# How to implement login with Facebook functionality in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, api

I am working on an Android app.There are two options for login here. I want to know how I can implement the functionality to allow a user to log in with Facebook..There will be two buttons: one for simple login, and the other login using Facebook. When the user clicks on "Login with Facebook", it should ask for Facebook username and password for first time and other times it should automatically login with Facebook credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Check directly on facebook developer site.
https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Download the latest sdk.
Register yourself as facebook developer 
Create App ID and Use that App id in your android app.
For more details see facebook integration example : You can see the sample code in sdk manager, that you would download from devloper site.

Answer (score 0):

go to the following link download facebook sdk , it also contains the sample for facebook.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

and you need facebook sdk to access login so, from below link you can get sdk

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: The link to the tutorial above is outdated and uses deprecated classes in the Facebook SDK. You should go directly to the facebook developer site for the latest tutorials and updates. https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Answer (score 0):

When you click on button will open dialog for facebook authentication and then will return users information such as id, name, email as per permission. (Make sure you have set up library in android studio,and added facebook id in string.xml).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    // Application code
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,object.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show();
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,exception.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends","email"));
        }
    });
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```